# force close when try to call a class that implements a Client Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, client, runnable

I have a client-sever app on android,both running on the same machine.
In the first activity of my client app I try to call client class which should connect to the server application,but I get force close.

This is how I call the client class in the first activity of my app:

```
Thread cThread=new Thread(new ClientThread());
cThread.start();
```

and here is my client class:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    private Handler handler=new Handler();
    Socket  socket;
    private TextView clientState;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr=InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText(" try to connect!");
                }
            });
        socket=new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);

            //connected=true;
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Connected!");
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Error");
                    }
            });

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

      protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            try {
                 // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
                //out.close();
                 socket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }

}
```

Can someone tell what is wrong or at least give me an ideea.
One thing that I should say is that my client works fine-it connects to the server,when the client class is integrated in my first activity(I mean,initially I had no client class was all in the first activity...and it worked fine).
I'm here for further details!
Thank u in advance!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Without the stack trace it looks like it crashes cause you didn't initialize the textview.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    }

    public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    ...// Do NOT init textview
    }
}
```

Comment: That may be true, but you appear to create a new TextView in this class. And you never init it in the class.

Comment: Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 26 in screen1)) 
 screen1.onCreate(Bundle) line: 26 
 Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047 
 ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2459 
 ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512 
 ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
 ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863 
 ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99

Comment: Looper.loop() line: 123 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Comment: Yes,is a inner class.Could be the handler the problem?

Comment: Just because it is in the XML, doesn't mean the Java code can see it. (inherently). You still have to set the contentView of the activity to the unique id of the layout and then init the widget.

Comment: Maybe, truthfully, I can barely read the stack trace, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Well,u were right...I don't get force close anymore cause I gave up displaying the text.....But could u explain me how could I do to still display the text?I'm new to android so if u could explain it in details would be teriffic.Thx

Comment: I will update my answer with a standard method of doing so. Also review the documentation. It is extremely helpful for starting out. http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html

Comment: Hehe, I would like to help, but it would be a better idea to just keep posting new questions. Usually you'll get better help for others than from me. I also should be working, but I'm a slacker. ; )